# How can I bind two SimpleDoubleProperty`s to each other with an exponential relation? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, properties, relation, exponential

I know how to do a binding like this:

```
doublePropertyOne.bind(doublePropertyTwo.multiply(2));
```

What I need is the example above with an exponential relation:

```
doublePropertyOne.bind(doublePropertyTwo.asExponentialOfE());
```

So that i get an doubleProperty which equals E^doubleProperty.
Is there any way to accomplish this relation or how else would you implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Bindings` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) to crate a binding that depends on `doublePropertyTwo`:

```
doublePropertyOne.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> Math.exp(doublePropertyTwo.get()), doublePropertyTwo));
```

Here the `Callable` passed as first parameter to `createDoubleBinding` is reevaluated every time the dependencies passed starting with the second parameter (in this case `doublePropertyTwo`) change.